# Create database with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, entity

I'm trying to create a database called Todo with Entity Framework. I want this database to appear in Sql Server Management after it has been created.

I have the context file:

```
namespace Domain
{
    //Associate the model with the database
    //This class then automatically defines a property for each table in the database that I want to work with.
    public class EFDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public EFDbContext() : base("EFDbContext")
        {
        }
        public DbSet<List> Lists { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I have my Initializer:

```
namespace Domain
{
    public class ListRepository : System.Data.Entity.DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<EFDbContext>
    {
        protected override void Seed(EFDbContext context)
        {
            var todo = new List<List>
            {
                new List { Day="Månadg" },
                new List { Day="Tisdag" },
                new List { Day="Onsdag" },
                new List { Day="Torsdag" },
                new List { Day="Fredag" }
            };

            todo.ForEach(t => context.Lists.Add(t));
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

And here I have my Web.Config:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="EFDbContext" connectionString="Data Source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Todo;Integrated Security=SSPI;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

    <contexts>
      <context type="todo.domain.EFDbContext, todo">
        <databaseInitializer type="todo.domain.ListRepository, todo"></databaseInitializer>
      </context>
    </contexts>
```

When I run my application, I Data Connections Is created In Server Explorer as In the picture below:

[image: asd]

When I click on this Data Connection, I get the following error message:

[image: enter image asdhere]

When I check In Sql Server Management, no database is listed there. What am I doing wrong here? Why is the not database created?

As you can see, I have a solution called Todo, and In the Todo-solution, I have three projects. I have the DbContext In the Domain-project.

Answer (score 0):

From your screenshot, it says login failed for user Bryan in your message. This would mean Bryan is unable to connect

Check the following 3 items

1. From your Sql Management studio, open the Db, right icons and scroll down to security, (in windows authentication mode, usually easiest) and scroll down to security and then `add Bryan as a user giving him DBO rights`
2. `Authentication type` Check is Mixed Mode authentication is enabled
3. Switch the connection to Authentication and try with `SA` role